# Reactivate disabled user via the Workfront API

Tags: attask, workfront-api

Hello I have been able to figure out how to disable a user and re-enable a user using the api for Workfront.  I am having an issue with assigning a license for a user.  I am trying to set the licenseType=T for the worker license but that does not seem to be working.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To active/deactivate a user you can pass to the parameter isActive this is a true/false Boolean value. In regards to the License type this is an Automatic field that is modified by what Access Level the user has. This field cannot be modified directly. But setting the  accessLevelID will set this based on the license type of the Access Level.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have been able to set IsActive. I do see accessLevelID. Is there a list of what the accessLevelID are or how to link to them?

Comment: figured it out.  Thanks for your help